# How do I get text from an Afxwnd40 control in a 3rd-party application, using API calls in VBA?

Tags: api, vba, hook, sendmessage, afx

I am trying to write a script to interact with a lookup form in a 3rd-party application.

The form has a number of text boxes, corresponding to fields like "phone number" and "customer ID", as well as a command button, captioned "lookup".

When the command button is clicked, a multi-column listbox on the form is populated with any records in the database that match the criterion given. The user must then double-click the specific record, which opens up a new dialog box with options to "adjust" the record in question.

I did not make this form, and I do not have direct access to the database it pulls from; the form only allows users to adjust one record at a time.

I would like my script to copy a list of phone numbers from an Excel sheet one at a time, paste them into the correct field on the form, click the "lookup" button, and if one of the fields of the record in the listbox matches a pre-determined value, open the adjustment dialog and change the record.

I got as far as using FindWindow and FindWindowEx to get the handles of the fields I want to paste text into, and using the SendMesage function to interact with the form.

I am stuck on how to read the data from the listbox that comes up. It does not support copying or pasting, so I can't use SendMessage or SendKeys. Using WinSpy++, the listbox's class is "Afxwnd40", which, from a cursory search of online help forums, is a legacy control that directly "paints" text without the ability to copy it. I have heard some things about using a "hook" to capture data as it is sent to the window in question, but I don't know how to set that up. The only tools I have at my disposal are WinSpy++ and any Windows API calls in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but I was looking for a solution to automate Afx controls. There isn't a way to do this in VBA reliably at all. So a proper automation tool is needed.

QTP/UFT had trouble with getting the text of these controls and OCR just sucks.
But I found that Ranorex has the ability to get raw text from objects at the GDI layer.

In Ranorex in the element browser, right click on the Afx control and select 'Add to GDI capture'. You'll find Ranorex will behave with that object a lot better now.